# SSRS ReportViewer nullreference exception on Disposing

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, dispose

We're currently using a Windows Service to generate PDF files. I was recently optimizing the code and noticed the abusive use of memory. This was caused by the lack of a **using** statement around `var reportViewer = new ReportViewer()`

However, after adding this the code threw a runtime nullreference exception after closing the **using** block, the code originating in the internal **Dispose** method.

Why does this error occur and how can I dispose the object properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, as can be found in Visual Basic [here](http://blog.700cb.net/index.php/2015/03/13/ssrs-reportviewer-nullreferenceexception-on-dispose/) is because for some reason the ReportViewer expects a HttpContext. If none is present, this error will occur.

As a workaround the following lines can be added to resolve the issue:

```
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current == null)
                {
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = new System.Web.HttpContext(
                        new System.Web.HttpRequest(System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName(), "https://www.stackoverflow.com", string.Empty),
                        new System.Web.HttpResponse(System.IO.TextWriter.Null)
                        );
                }
```

This will create a fake HttpContext, allowing somehow to dispose the ReportViewer instance properly.